# Logging & Monitoring for Hive Batch Jobs

Tags: logging, hive, architecture, batch-processing

This is my first question in this forum. I am writing hive batch job logs into a hive log table as-soon-as each step completed. I am using `INSERT INTO TABLE` for writing logs into hive table.
In hive, multiple records are created for each batch job ID, so I am creating a View to combine logging data collected before using in monitoring tool.
Can you please suggest any better solution to achieve this?

**Notes:**

1. My batch job having multiple steps and I like to collect logs from each step
2. I don't want to use UPDATE
3. I am unable to upload image.
   `Batch Job -> Logs -> Hive -> Monitoring`

Comment: IMHO better solution is to monitor logs in files using Splunk, do not load them in Hive tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the reference architecture I can suggest. You can still use Hive for logging, but use `SERDEPROPERTIES` to integrate with `HBase`.

**Benefits:**

- Data will be stored in HBase, which will allow to decide a KEY for data override (example: Batch Job ID)
- HBase will maintain the versions
- You can able to query Hive the way you normally access Hive tables
- Real-time dashboard using HBase data

**High-Level Diagram:**
[image]

Comment: Please consider voting up the answer if it helped !